# Stuck in a C project(Quiz)

Tags: c, while-loop

I am a beginner in C and I am working on a quiz. Everything is going well but I want to count the user's correct answers and display them at the end of the quiz using `while` or `for`. I have searched for hours but couldn't find anything. If anyone could help me it will be much appreciated!

Here is my code (the non-english are the questions):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, a, answer, B, i;

    printf("Καλώς ήρθατε στο quiz/εργασία:)\n");
    printf("Αυτό το κουίζ περιέχει ερωτήσεις για χώρες επειδή δεν ήθελα να βάλω μαθηματικά\n");
  press:
    printf("Πάτα *1* για έναρξη\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (x <= 1) {
        printf("Πρεπει να απαντησεις συνολικα 8 ερωτησεις\n");
        goto start;
    } else
    if (x > 1) {
        goto press;
    }
  start:
    switch (x) {
      case 1:
        {
            printf("ποια ειναι η πρωτεύουσα της Ρουμανίας;:\n");
            printf("1=Κραϊοβα, 2=Βουκουρέστη, 3=Βουδαπέστη, 4=Οραντέα\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer == 2) {
                while (i = 1) {
                    i += 1;
                }
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η 'Βουδαπέστη.'\n");
            } else
            if (answer == 1, 3, 4) {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 2:
        {
            printf("ποια χώρα κατανάλλωσε το περισσότερο τσάι το 2022;:\n");
            printf("1=Ιρλανδία, 2=Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο, 3=Τουρκία, 4=Ινδονησία\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer == 3) {
                while (i <= 1) {
                    i += 1;
                }
                printf("Σωστό!Με τον μέσο Τούρκο να καταναλλωνει 3.16kg ετησίως.\n");
            } else
            if (answer == 1, 2, 4) {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 3:
        {
            printf("Ποια από τις παρακάτω χώρες έχουν 3 πρωτεύουσες;:\n");
            printf("1=Ελβετία, 2=Νότια Αφρική, 3=Κίνα, 4=Αυστραλία\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer == 2) {
                while (i <= 2) {
                    i += 1;
                }
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Νότια Αφρική(1:Κέιπ τάουν, 2:Πρετόρια, 3:Μπλουμφοντέιν.\n");
            } else
            if (answer == 1, 3, 4) {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 4:
        {
            printf("Ποιανής χώρας ο εθνικός ύμνος δεν έχει στίχους;:\n");
            printf("1=Μάλτα, 2=Νορβηγία, 3=Ισλανδία, 4=Ισπανία\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer == 4) {
                while (i <= 3) {
                    i += 1;
                }
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Ισπανία.\n");
            } else
            if (answer == 1, 3, 2) {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 5:
        {
            printf("ποια ειναι η πρωτεύουσα της Εσθονίας;:\n");
            printf("1=Ταλίν, 2=Τάρτου, 3=Νάρβα, 4=Ρακβερέ\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer == 1) {
                while (i <= 4) {
                    i+=1;
                }
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι το Ταλίν.\n");
            } else
            if (answer == 2, 3, 4) {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 6:
        {
            printf("Ποια είναι η μικρότερη χώρα της κεντρικής Αμερικής;:\n");
            printf("1=Ελ Σαλβαδόρ, 2=Ονδούρα, 3=Νικαράγουα, 4=Γουατεμάλα\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer == 1) {
                while (i <= 5) {
                    i += 1;
                }
                printf("Σωστό!Είναι το Ελ Σαλβαδόρ με έδαφος μόλις 21,041km²\n");
            } else
            if (answer == 2, 3, 4) {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 7:
        {
            printf("Ποια χώρα έχει τις περισσότερες ζώνες ώρας;:\n");
            printf("1=Ρωσία, 2=ΗΠΑ, 3=Γαλλία, 4=Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer == 3) {
                while (i <= 6) {
                    i += 1;
                }
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Γαλλία με 12 ζώνες ώρας(+παραθαλάσσια εδάφη).\n");
            } else
            if (answer == 1, 2, 4) {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 8:
        {
            printf("Ποια ήπειρος φιλοξενεί τις περισσότερες χώρες;:\n");
            printf("1=Ευρώπη, 2=Νότια Αμερική, 3=Αφρική, 4=Ασία\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);
            if (answer == 3) {
                while (i <= 7) {
                    i += 1;
                }
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Αφρική με 54 χώρες.\n");
            } else
            if (answer == 1, 2, 4) {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
        printf("απαντησες σωστα %d\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to put the while element in different locations in various forms but nothing worked. The closest I got to "Work" is the answer `you answered right- 32767`.

Comment: Um.. was it intentional that *none* of your `case` selects have a `break` ? Somehow, I'm doubting it was.

Comment: Yeah, I could fix that but I firstly want to write all the elements needed and then scan for mistakes and make the code look better.

Comment: Please choose a title which actually describes your problem, not a generic statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first making it as simple as possible. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int answer = 0;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Καλώς ήρθατε στο quiz/εργασία:)\n");
    printf(
        "Αυτό το κουίζ περιέχει ερωτήσεις για χώρες επειδή δεν ήθελα να βάλω μαθηματικά\n");

    printf("ποια ειναι η πρωτεύουσα της Ρουμανίας;:\n");
    printf("1=Κραϊοβα, 2=Βουκουρέστη, 3=Βουδαπέστη, 4=Οραντέα\n");

    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (answer == 2) {
        printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η 'Βουδαπέστη.'\n");
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("Λαθος.\n");
    }

    printf("ποια χώρα κατανάλλωσε το περισσότερο τσάι το 2022;:\n");
    printf("1=Ιρλανδία, 2=Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο, 3=Τουρκία, 4=Ινδονησία\n");

    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (answer == 3) {
        printf("Σωστό!Με τον μέσο Τούρκο να καταναλλωνει 3.16kg ετησίως.\n");
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("Λαθος.\n");
    }

    printf("Ποια από τις παρακάτω χώρες έχουν 3 πρωτεύουσες;:\n");
    printf("1=Ελβετία, 2=Νότια Αφρική, 3=Κίνα, 4=Αυστραλία\n");

    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (answer == 2) {
        printf(
            "Σωστό!Ειναι η Νότια Αφρική(1:Κέιπ τάουν, 2:Πρετόρια, 3:Μπλουμφοντέιν.\n");
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("Λαθος.\n");
    }

    printf("Ποιανής χώρας ο εθνικός ύμνος δεν έχει στίχους;:\n");
    printf("1=Μάλτα, 2=Νορβηγία, 3=Ισλανδία, 4=Ισπανία\n");

    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (answer == 4) {
        printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Ισπανία.\n");
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("Λαθος.\n");
    }

    printf("ποια ειναι η πρωτεύουσα της Εσθονίας;:\n");
    printf("1=Ταλίν, 2=Τάρτου, 3=Νάρβα, 4=Ρακβερέ\n");

    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (answer == 1) {
        printf("Σωστό!Ειναι το Ταλίν.\n");
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("Λαθος.\n");
    }

    printf("Ποια είναι η μικρότερη χώρα της κεντρικής Αμερικής;:\n");
    printf("1=Ελ Σαλβαδόρ, 2=Ονδούρα, 3=Νικαράγουα, 4=Γουατεμάλα\n");

    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (answer == 1) {
        printf("Σωστό!Είναι το Ελ Σαλβαδόρ με έδαφος μόλις 21,041km²\n");
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("Λαθος.\n");
    }

    printf("Ποια χώρα έχει τις περισσότερες ζώνες ώρας;:\n");
    printf("1=Ρωσία, 2=ΗΠΑ, 3=Γαλλία, 4=Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο\n");

    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (answer == 3) {
        printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Γαλλία με 12 ζώνες ώρας(+παραθαλάσσια εδάφη).\n");
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("Λαθος.\n");
    }

    printf("Ποια ήπειρος φιλοξενεί τις περισσότερες χώρες;:\n");
    printf("1=Ευρώπη, 2=Νότια Αμερική, 3=Αφρική, 4=Ασία\n");

    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if (answer == 3) {
        printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Αφρική με 54 χώρες.\n");
        count++;
    } else {
        printf("Λαθος.\n");
    }

    printf("απαντησες σωστα %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `i` is not initialized. If you mean to count the number of correct answers, name the variable `count` and initialize it to `0`.
- `while (i = 1) { i += 1; } is an endless loop as` i = 1`**sets**`i`to`1`instead of comparing`i`to`1`, which is written` i == 1`.
- all loops `while (i <= 2) { i += 1; }` are equivalent to `if (i <= 2) { i = 3; }`.  You should probably just count the number of correct answers.
- `if (answer == 1, 3, 4)` is a constant test that is always true, because the `,` in the test expression is an operator that evaluates to its second operand. Note that this test is redundant anyway. You should just use `else {`
- the initial iteration using labels and `goto` statements should be changed.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, answer, count = 0;

    printf("Καλώς ήρθατε στο quiz/εργασία:)\n");
    printf("Αυτό το κουίζ περιέχει ερωτήσεις για χώρες επειδή δεν ήθελα να βάλω μαθηματικά\n");
    for (;;) {
        printf("Πάτα *1* για έναρξη\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
            return 1;
        if (x < 1) {
            printf("Πρεπει να απαντησεις συνολικα 8 ερωτησεις\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    switch (x) {
      case 1:
        {
            printf("ποια ειναι η πρωτεύουσα της Ρουμανίας;:\n");
            printf("1=Κραϊοβα, 2=Βουκουρέστη, 3=Βουδαπέστη, 4=Οραντέα\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
                break;
            if (answer == 2) {
                count += 1;
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η 'Βουδαπέστη.'\n");
            } else {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 2:
        {
            printf("ποια χώρα κατανάλλωσε το περισσότερο τσάι το 2022;:\n");
            printf("1=Ιρλανδία, 2=Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο, 3=Τουρκία, 4=Ινδονησία\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
                break;
            if (answer == 3) {
                count += 1;
                printf("Σωστό!Με τον μέσο Τούρκο να καταναλλωνει 3.16kg ετησίως.\n");
            } else {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 3:
        {
            printf("Ποια από τις παρακάτω χώρες έχουν 3 πρωτεύουσες;:\n");
            printf("1=Ελβετία, 2=Νότια Αφρική, 3=Κίνα, 4=Αυστραλία\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
                break;
            if (answer == 2) {
                count += 1;
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Νότια Αφρική(1:Κέιπ τάουν, 2:Πρετόρια, 3:Μπλουμφοντέιν.\n");
            } else {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 4:
        {
            printf("Ποιανής χώρας ο εθνικός ύμνος δεν έχει στίχους;:\n");
            printf("1=Μάλτα, 2=Νορβηγία, 3=Ισλανδία, 4=Ισπανία\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
                break;
            if (answer == 4) {
                count += 1;
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Ισπανία.\n");
            } else {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 5:
        {
            printf("ποια ειναι η πρωτεύουσα της Εσθονίας;:\n");
            printf("1=Ταλίν, 2=Τάρτου, 3=Νάρβα, 4=Ρακβερέ\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
                break;
            if (answer == 1) {
                count += 1;
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι το Ταλίν.\n");
            } else {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 6:
        {
            printf("Ποια είναι η μικρότερη χώρα της κεντρικής Αμερικής;:\n");
            printf("1=Ελ Σαλβαδόρ, 2=Ονδούρα, 3=Νικαράγουα, 4=Γουατεμάλα\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
                break;
            if (answer == 1) {
                count += 1;
                printf("Σωστό!Είναι το Ελ Σαλβαδόρ με έδαφος μόλις 21,041km²\n");
            } else {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 7:
        {
            printf("Ποια χώρα έχει τις περισσότερες ζώνες ώρας;:\n");
            printf("1=Ρωσία, 2=ΗΠΑ, 3=Γαλλία, 4=Ηνωμένο Βασίλειο\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
                break;
            if (answer == 3) {
                count += 1;
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Γαλλία με 12 ζώνες ώρας(+παραθαλάσσια εδάφη).\n");
            } else {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
      case 8:
        {
            printf("Ποια ήπειρος φιλοξενεί τις περισσότερες χώρες;:\n");
            printf("1=Ευρώπη, 2=Νότια Αμερική, 3=Αφρική, 4=Ασία\n");
            if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1)
                break;
            if (answer == 3) {
                count += 1;
                printf("Σωστό!Ειναι η Αφρική με 54 χώρες.\n");
            } else {
                printf("Λαθος.\n");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("απαντησες σωστα %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The count element is working but can you tell me what the for(;;){ } does?   
                                                                                                                                           
Thank's for your effort I really appreciate it!

Comment: @GeorgeChristou: `for (;;) { ...}` is a *for ever* loop, idiomatic in C. You could also write `while (1) { ... }`

Comment: I mean that I dont think its correct because it just loops the "press *1* to start" and if I remove it the program is working as it should.

Comment: The `for(;;)` loop iterates until the user types a number greater or equal to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest some other code that simplifies things

First of all, you will find soon that **goto** is not suggested as best practice.

Below find and explanation of the program:

- I start my main program by creating two arrays, one for the questions and one for the right answers.
- Then I make a do-while where I loop the question until someone presses 1.
- When someone presses 1, i loop as many times as the questions. I find the questions number with *sizeof(questions)/sizeof(questions[0])* which divides the whole length of questions by the size of a single question element.
- I this for loop i run a function that takes as parameters the question and the right answer and if my input equals the right answer it returns 1, else 0
- Returning from the function, I can add the returned value to a variable i declared (iscorrect) which will not be affected if the answer is not correct. But if it is it will be +1.

Ending the loop i have the right answers number in my variable *iscorrect*

If you wish to have explanations for the right answers you can always add an exrta array an pass it as a parameter to the function, and make it print insted of a simple 'correct' i added for testing.

**Functions** help you keep your code clean and organized, they also minimise space & time, as you can write it once and call it as many times as you want in your code

Hope I helped

```
#include <stdio.h>

int AskQuestion (char Question[], int rightanswer){
    int answer = "";
    printf(Question);
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if(answer==rightanswer){
        printf("Right\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
     printf("Wrong\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int x;
    char questions[3][250] = {
        "Question 1: ..........",
        "Question 2: ..........",
        "Question 3: .........."
        };

        int answers[3] = {
        1,
        2,
        1
        };
  printf("String array Elements are:\n");

    printf("Welcome to the quiz\n");
    do{
        printf("Press *1* to start\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }
    while(x!=1);

    int iscorrect =0;

    int questionslength = sizeof(questions)/sizeof(questions[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<questionslength; i++){

        char question[] = "";
        int  rightanswer = 1;

        iscorrect += AskQuestion(questions[i], answers[i]);
    }

    printf("Right answers %d\n",iscorrect);
    return 0;
}
```